# Trying to get a partial to load in side of my django template using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am using Angular with my Django application what I want to do is add a partial to my sheet_form_create.html page. everything works with no errors in my browser console, but for some reason my partial isn't showing up any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my add_dim_angular.js

```
dim_app = angular.module('dim_form', []) 


  .controller('dim_ctrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) { 

      $scope.show_dim = function () { 
          var comp = $compile("<div my-Dim</div>")($scope); 
          $("#d").append(comp); 
      }; 
  }]) 
  .directive('my-Dim', function () { 
      return { 
          templateUrl: '/sheet/sheet_form_create.html/_dim' 

      }; 
  });
```

here is my sheet_form_create.html

```
    {% extends "app/layout.html" %} 
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
    {% block content %} 



    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 



    <div class="row" > 
      {% crispy sheet_form %} 
    </div> 

    <body ng-app="dim_form"> 
      <div ng-controller="dim_ctrl"> 
          <a href="#" ng-click="show_dim()">show</a> 
          <div id="d"></div> 
      </div> 
    </body> 

    {% endblock %}
```

here is my rendered partial _dim

```
<html><head></head><body><br> 
<br> 
<br> 


<div class="my-Dim"> 


<form data-parsley-validate="1" id="dim_new" class="form-horizontal" method="post"> <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="B3dLOy9inLwzBeuHcR422ePrnCuIaSY4" type="hidden"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_description" class="control-group"> <label for="id_description" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Description<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_description" maxlength="255" name="description" parsley-maxlength="255" parsley-minlength="2" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." type="text"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_style" class="control-group"> <label for="id_style" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Style<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_style" maxlength="255" name="style" parsley-maxlength="255" parsley-minlength="2" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." type="text"> </div> </div> </div> 

</div> 
<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_target" class="control-group"> <label for="id_target" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Target<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_target" name="target" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_upper_limit" class="control-group"> <label for="id_upper_limit" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Upper limit<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_upper_limit" name="upper_limit" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_lower_limit" class="control-group"> <label for="id_lower_limit" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Lower limit<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_lower_limit" name="lower_limit" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 

</div> 
<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-2"> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_critical" class="control-group"> <label for="id_critical" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Critical<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_critical" name="critical" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_units" class="control-group"> <label for="id_units" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Units<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_units" maxlength="255" name="units" parsley-maxlength="255" parsley-minlength="2" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." type="text"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_metric" class="control-group"> <label for="id_metric" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Metric<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_metric" maxlength="255" name="metric" parsley-maxlength="255" parsley-minlength="2" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." type="text"> </div> </div> </div> 

</div> 
<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_target_strings" class="control-group"> <label for="id_target_strings" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Target strings<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_target_strings" maxlength="255" name="target_strings" parsley-maxlength="255" parsley-minlength="2" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." type="text"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_ref_dim_id" class="control-group"> <label for="id_ref_dim_id" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Ref dim id<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_ref_dim_id" name="ref_dim_id" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_nested_number" class="control-group"> <label for="id_nested_number" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Nested number<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_nested_number" name="nested_number" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_position" class="control-group"> <label for="id_position" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Position<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_position" name="position" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 

</div> 
<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_met_upper" class="control-group"> <label for="id_met_upper" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Met upper<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_met_upper" name="met_upper" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_met_lower" class="control-group"> <label for="id_met_lower" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Met lower<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_met_lower" name="met_lower" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_valc" class="control-group"> <label for="id_valc" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Valc<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="textinput textInput" id="id_valc" name="valc" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." type="text"> </div> </div> </div> 
<div class="col-md-2"> <div id="div_id_sheet_id" class="control-group"> <label for="id_sheet_id" class="control-label requiredField"> 
                Sheet id<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <input class="numberinput" id="id_sheet_id" name="sheet_id" parsley-required="true" parsley-required-message="This field is required." parsley-type="digits" parsley-type-message="Enter a whole number." type="number"> </div> </div> </div> 

</div> 
<br> <br><div class="form-actions"> <input name="save_dims" value="Save Dims" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary" id="submit-id-save_dims" type="submit"> 
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/sheet/sheet_form_create.html">Cancel</a> 
</div> </form> 

</div> 

</body></html>
```

Comment: If you look at the network tab in your browser, you should see that file being loaded at some point. Is that the case? Can you also check whether the `<div my-Dim>` elemebt appears in the inspect tab? There may be an error in your JS as the `<div>` tag lacks a `>`

Comment: I found the issue  in "var comp = $compile("<div my-Dim</div>")($scope); " I am missing the closing > in <div my-Dim">"</div> I fixed it and presto it works thank you for your comment  @raphv

Comment: If you put that for the answer I will accept it seeing how you beat me to my mistake lol @raphv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the closing > in "